# How to analyze the "max" method

Tags: ruby, string

Can someone explain why `"time"` is the max value here?

```
my_array = %w{hello my time here is long}
my_array.max  #=> "time"
```

Comment: The docs have the answer: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E

Comment: ["lexicographic sorting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order); see also [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: Get in the habit of checking things like this in irb.

Comment: Thanks all! It makes sense now.

Comment: Follow the advise of others and get used to read the documentation, e.g. with ri (`ri Array#max`). However, it comes down to String#<=> which does not go into detail of lexicographical order (its condensed in the word "greater" and examples) - actually improvable!

Answer (score 2):

Because alphabetically `t` in `time` is greater here among others in your array `my_array`.

Here is one way,how string comparisons happened :

```
'hello' >  'time' # => false
'my' > 'time' # => false
'here' > 'time' # => false
'is' > 'time' # => false
'long' > 'time' # => false
```

To understand the outputs of the above fragment code,you must need to see [`String#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) documentation. As your `my_array` contains all string instances,which has called the method `<=>`,to build the output of `max`.

Documentations says [`Enumerable#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

> Enumerable#max,without block *assumes all objects implement [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Comparable.html#method-i-3C).*

Comment: "bigger" is probably not the word you meant. "greater" would apply more correctly to character order comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how computers look at the strings and compare them.

If we look at the first characters of each word it'll help a little, because we know how the alphabet orders letters:

```
%w[hello my time here is long].map{ |s| s[0] }.sort # => ["h", "h", "i", "l", "m", "t"]
```

But that doesn't really help visualize it, so here's a look at each word's letters as a computer sees them:

```
%w[time tome].each do |w|
  puts w.chars.map(&:ord).join(', ')
end
# >> 116, 105, 109, 101
# >> 116, 111, 109, 101
```

Each letter has a value. Over the years there have been many different ways of ordering letters for a computer, which caused the character to value mapping to change. [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) have been the most popular but have different orders. We're usually dealing with ASCII, or a derivative, which is set by the OS.

Look at how the characters in the words are represented by the values in the following output. It should make it easy to understand what the computer is doing then.

```
%w[he hello help holler hollow].sort.each do |w|
  puts '"%6s": %s' % [ w, w.chars.map(&:ord).join(', ') ]
end
# >> "    he": 104, 101
# >> " hello": 104, 101, 108, 108, 111
# >> "  help": 104, 101, 108, 112
# >> "holler": 104, 111, 108, 108, 101, 114
# >> "hollow": 104, 111, 108, 108, 111, 119
```